# HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem method is missing

Tags: c#, vb.net, asynchronous

I am working in .NET framework 4.8 (correction: my Visual Studio installation was 4.8, the application was targeting 4.5 - this was the source of the problem, which is now solved) and trying to use the QueueBackgroundWorkItem method of the HostingEnvironment class, but when I write it into my code, I get this message:

BC30456: 'QueueBackgroundWorkItem' is not a member of 'HostingEnvironment'.

I have used Imports System.Web.Hosting at the top of my script. System.Web.Hosting imports OK and the HostingEnvironment class shows up highlighted in my code, as it should. The class HostingEnvironment is recognised and has methods, but QueueBackgroundWorkItem isn't one of them.

I get a similar error when I try to use this method in C#.

CS0426: The type name 'QueueBackgroundWorkItem' does not exist in the type 'HostingEnvironment'.

I've searched for the System.Web.Hosting library in NuGet to see if there were any updates, but nothing came up. Google searches for these errors haven't got me anywhere, other than to links explaining how to use the HostingEnvironment method.

Comment: **How** certain are you that you're actually targetting .NET 4.8? If you're targetting an older version (4.5 say) then it won't be available.

Comment: Thanks Damien, great question. I will check that. I was going by the version of .NET in my installation of VS.

Comment: Solved. You're right, it is targeting 4.5, at least I think so according to the debug and release obj names. .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.